# Cant access my websites inside virtualbox after the last Windows 10 update

Tags: networking, windows-10, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

- Host: Windows 10 (updated)
- Guest: Ubuntu 14.04.5
- Virtualbox: 5.2.12 r122591 (Qt5.6.2)

After the windows update I tried to access my virtual machine and it kept giving me random errors. After of dozens of tutorials and guides my current settings are:

Hosts file (on windows): 192.168.56.2 devserver 
Changed it to 192.168.10.3 devserver (as comments suggest)

I've disabled my DHCP servers

[Running dmesg command gives me this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slM8R.jpg)

/etc/network/interfaces file(on ubuntu)(couldn't paste):

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.56.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.56.0

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth2
iface eth2 inet dhcp
```

Virtualbox network:

- Attached to: Host-only Adapter
- Name: VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #3
- Adapter Type: PCnet-FAST III (am79C973)
- Promiscuous Mode: Allow All
- MAC Address: 0800275A1DBB
- Portforward: The button is grayed out

When starting the machine an error occurs: "Waiting for netowork configuration" than "Waiting 60 more seconds"

[ifconfig (couldn't copy paste)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KxGp.png)

But I still can't connect to the website. It keeps giving me the "page not found" message. I'm stuck in this for days.

Comment: Network VB bridge or nat? Port fowarding? What says ifconfig?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I added the information you asked to the main post.

Comment: @3D1T0R Fixed it hehehe

Comment: Try this in your windows host fle "192.168.10.3 devserver"  that at least corresponds to the only working NIC that Ubuntu is aware of.  If it does not succeed, please show the result of "dmesg | grep eth"

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I've tried the 192.168.10.3 before and tried it again with no success. After running the dmesg command, a huge text showed up ending in https://imgur.com/duQQLH7. After running grep eth, nothing happens and I have to restart the system because I can't issue any commands anymore

Comment: "dmesg | grep eth" is one command, not two separately.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I'm so sorry, here is the result you asked https://imgur.com/plsDo7K

Comment: So there is only one card, give my answer a try.  If you don't mind me saying it, I'm afraid you're trying to run before you can walk.

Comment: @GabrielPereira Questions shouldn’t contain their solution/answer

Comment: Sorry I'll remove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your /etc/network/interfaces as follows (why did you define 3 NICs ??):

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.56.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.56.0
```

Your hosts file on Windows should be restored to your original settings

```
192.168.52.2 devserver
```

Restart the VB.

Comment: This is the solution (after correcting the typo 52 to 56)

I don't know why there were 3 NICs, I tried dozens of guides and tutorials and I would have a hard time finding the one that suggested this. It was a long week.

Comment: This fixed the bug at the startup that made me wait 2 minutes as well

Comment: Perhaps DHCP timeout for the two inexistant NICs ?